# Swimlane - GoJS library

Tags: javascript, json, gojs

I would like to ask, if anyone knows how to convert the orientation of the diagram of swimlanes in GOjs library [from being top-level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnvWl.png) to a [single row orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flZWd.png), it is because I want to have a diagram that connects a node to another from a different group.

And also is it possible to add attributes to each node, like onmouseover, class, id, name, and etc.?

Currently I have this copied and paste code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Swimlane</title>
<!-- Copyright 1998-2014 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<link href="goSamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="go.js"></script>
<script id="code">

  // These parameters need to be set before defining the templates.

  // this controls whether the swimlanes are horizontal stacked vertically, or the other way:
  var HORIZONTAL = true;
  // this controls the minimum length of any swimlane
  var MINLENGTH = 200;
  // this controls the minimum breadth of any swimlane
  var MINBREADTH = 100;


  // compute the minimum length needed to hold all of the subgraphs
  function computeMinPlaceholderSize(diagram) {
    var len = MINLENGTH;
    for (var it = diagram.nodes; it.next(); ) {
      var group = it.value;
      if (!(group instanceof go.Group)) continue;
      var holder = group.placeholder;
      if (holder !== null) {
        var sz = holder.actualBounds;
        len = Math.max(len, (HORIZONTAL ? sz.width : sz.height));
      }
    }
    return (HORIZONTAL ? new go.Size(len, NaN) : new go.Size(NaN, len));
  }

  // get the minimum placeholder size for a particular Group;
  // when group is null, return the minimum size
  function computePlaceholderSize(group) {
    if (group instanceof go.Group) {
      var holder = group.placeholder;
      if (holder !== null) {
        return holder.actualBounds.size;
      }
    }
    return (HORIZONTAL ? new go.Size(MINLENGTH, MINBREADTH) : new go.Size(MINBREADTH, MINLENGTH));
  }


  // define a custom ResizingTool to limit how far one can shrink a Group
  function GroupResizingTool() {
    go.ResizingTool.call(this);
  }
  go.Diagram.inherit(GroupResizingTool, go.ResizingTool);

  GroupResizingTool.prototype.isLengthening = function() {
    return (this.handle.alignment === (HORIZONTAL ? go.Spot.Right : go.Spot.Bottom));
  };

  GroupResizingTool.prototype.computeMinSize = function() {
    var msz = computePlaceholderSize(null);  // get the minimum size
    if (this.isLengthening()) {  // compute the minimum length of all lanes
      var sz = computeMinPlaceholderSize(this.diagram);
      if (HORIZONTAL) {
        msz.width = Math.max(msz.width, sz.width);
      } else {
        msz.height = Math.max(msz.height, sz.height);
      }
    } else {  // find the minimum size of this single lane
      var sz = computePlaceholderSize(this.adornedObject.part);
      msz.width = Math.max(msz.width, sz.width);
      msz.height = Math.max(msz.height, sz.height);
    }
    return msz;
  };

  GroupResizingTool.prototype.resize = function(newr) {
    if (this.isLengthening()) {  // changing the length of all of the lanes
      for (var it = myDiagram.nodes; it.next(); ) {
        var group = it.value;
        if (!(group instanceof go.Group)) continue;
        var shape = group.findObject("SHAPE");
        if (shape !== null) {  // set its desiredSize, but leave the other direction alone
          if (HORIZONTAL) {
            shape.width = newr.width;
          } else {
            shape.height = newr.height;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {  // changing the breadth and length of a single lane
      go.ResizingTool.prototype.resize.call(this, newr);
    }
  };
  // end GroupResizingTool class


  // define a custom grid layout that makes sure the length of each lane is the same
  // and that each lane is broad enough to hold its subgraph
  function StackLayout() {
    go.GridLayout.call(this);
  }
  go.Diagram.inherit(StackLayout, go.GridLayout);

  StackLayout.prototype.doLayout = function(coll) {
    var diagram = this.diagram;
    if (diagram === null) return;
    diagram.startTransaction("StackLayout");
    // make sure all of the Group Shapes are big enough
    var minsize = computeMinPlaceholderSize(diagram);
    for (var it = diagram.nodes; it.next(); ) {
      var group = it.value;
      if (!(group instanceof go.Group)) continue;
      var shape = group.findObject("SHAPE");
      if (shape !== null) {  // change the desiredSize to be big enough in both directions
        var sz = computePlaceholderSize(group);
        if (HORIZONTAL) {
          shape.width = (isNaN(shape.width) ? minsize.width : Math.max(shape.width, minsize.width));
          if (!isNaN(shape.height)) shape.height = Math.max(shape.height, sz.height);
        } else {
          if (!isNaN(shape.width)) shape.width = Math.max(shape.width, sz.width);
          shape.height = (isNaN(shape.height) ? minsize.height : Math.max(shape.height, minsize.height));
        }
        var cell = group.resizeCellSize;
        if (!isNaN(shape.width) && !isNaN(cell.width) && cell.width > 0) shape.width = Math.ceil(shape.width / cell.width) * cell.width;
        if (!isNaN(shape.height) && !isNaN(cell.height) && cell.height > 0) shape.height = Math.ceil(shape.height / cell.height) * cell.height;
      }
    }
    // now do all of the usual stuff, according to whatever properties have been set on this GridLayout
    go.GridLayout.prototype.doLayout.call(this, coll);
    diagram.commitTransaction("StackLayout");
  };
  // end StackLayout class


  function init() {
    if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagram",
        {
          // use a custom ResizingTool (along with a custom ResizeAdornment on each Group)
          resizingTool: new GroupResizingTool(),
          // use a simple layout that ignores links to stack the top-level Groups on top of each other
          layout:
            $(StackLayout,
              {
                cellSize: new go.Size(1, 1),
                spacing: new go.Size(0, 0),
                wrappingColumn: (HORIZONTAL ? 1 : Infinity),
                wrappingWidth: Infinity,
                isViewportSized: false
              }),
          // don't allow dropping onto the diagram's background
          mouseDrop: function(e) { e.diagram.currentTool.doCancel(); },
          // a clipboard copied node is pasted into the original node's group (i.e. lane).
          "commandHandler.copiesGroupKey": true
        });

    // When a Node has been moved, make sure all of the top-level Groups get laid out again in a stack
    function relayoutDiagramStack(e) {
      myDiagram.layout.invalidateLayout();  // but don't invalidate all Layouts that are in Groups
      myDiagram.layoutDiagram();
    }
    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionMoved", relayoutDiagramStack);
    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionCopied", relayoutDiagramStack);

    // this is a Part.dragComputation function for limiting where a Node may be dragged
    function stayInGroup(part, pt, gridpt) {
      // don't constrain top-level nodes
      var grp = part.containingGroup;
      if (grp === null) return pt;
      // try to stay within the background Shape of the Group
      var back = grp.findObject("SHAPE");
      if (back === null) return pt;
      // allow dragging a Node out of a Group if the Shift key is down
      if (part.diagram.lastInput.shift) return pt;
      var b = part.actualBounds;
      var p1 = back.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.TopLeft);
      var p2 = back.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.BottomRight);
      // find the padding inside the group's placeholder that is around the member parts
      var m = grp.placeholder.padding;
      // now limit the location appropriately
      var x = Math.max(p1.x + m.left, Math.min(pt.x, p2.x - m.right - b.width - 1));
      var y = Math.max(p1.y + m.top, Math.min(pt.y, p2.y - m.bottom - b.height - 1));
      return new go.Point(x, y);
    }

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          { fill: "white", portId: "", cursor: "pointer", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true }),
        $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 5 },
          new go.Binding("text", "key")),
        // limit dragging of Nodes to stay within the containing Group, defined above
        {
          dragComputation: stayInGroup,
          mouseDrop: function (e, node) {  // dropping a copy of some Nodes and Links onto this Node adds them to this Node's Group
            if (!e.shift && !e.control) return;  // cannot change groups with an unmodified drag-and-drop
            var grp = node.containingGroup;
            if (grp !== null) {
              var ok = grp.addMembers(node.diagram.selection, true);
              if (!ok) grp.diagram.currentTool.doCancel();
            }
          },
          layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutAdded | go.Part.LayoutNodeSized
        }
      );

    // each Group is a "swimlane" with a header on the left and a resizable lane on the right
    myDiagram.groupTemplate =
      $(go.Group, HORIZONTAL ? "Horizontal" : "Vertical",
        {
          movable: false, copyable: false, deletable: false,  // can't move or copy or delete lanes
          avoidable: false,
          selectionObjectName: "SHAPE",  // selecting a lane causes the body of the lane to be highlit, not the label
          resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SHAPE",  // allow lanes to be resized, but the custom resizeAdornmentTemplate only permits one kind of resizing
          layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout,  // automatically lay out the lane's subgraph
                    { direction: HORIZONTAL ? 0 : 90, columnSpacing: 10, layeringOption: go.LayeredDigraphLayout.LayerLongestPathSource }),
          computesBoundsAfterDrag: true,  // needed to prevent recomputing Group.placeholder bounds too soon
          computesBoundsIncludingLinks: false,
          computesBoundsIncludingLocation: true,
          mouseDrop: function (e, grp) {  // dropping a copy of some Nodes and Links onto this Group adds them to this Group
            if (!e.shift && !e.control) return;  // cannot change groups with an unmodified drag-and-drop
            var ok = grp.addMembers(grp.diagram.selection, true);
            if (!ok) grp.diagram.currentTool.doCancel();
          }
        },
        // the lane header consisting of a Shape and a TextBlock
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
          { angle: HORIZONTAL ? 270 : 0,  // maybe rotate the header to read sideways going up
            alignment: go.Spot.Center },
          $(go.Shape, "Diamond",
            { width: 8, height: 8 },
            new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
          $(go.TextBlock,  // the lane label
            { font: "bold 16pt sans-serif" },
            new go.Binding("text", "key"))
        ),  // end Horizontal Panel
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",  // the lane consisting of a background Shape and a Placeholder representing the subgraph
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
            { name: "SHAPE", fill: "white", minSize: computePlaceholderSize(null) },
            new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
          $(go.Placeholder,
            { padding: 10, alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft })
        )  // end Auto Panel
      );  // end Group

    // define a custom resize adornment that only has a single resize handle
    myDiagram.groupTemplate.resizeAdornmentTemplate =
      $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
        $(go.Placeholder),
        $(go.Shape,  // for changing the length of a lane
          {
            alignment: HORIZONTAL ? go.Spot.Right: go.Spot.Bottom,
            desiredSize: HORIZONTAL ? new go.Size(7, 50) : new go.Size(50, 7),
            fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue",
            cursor: HORIZONTAL ? "col-resize" : "row-resize"
          }),
        $(go.Shape,  // for changing the breadth of a lane
          {
            alignment: HORIZONTAL ? go.Spot.Bottom : go.Spot.Right,
            desiredSize: HORIZONTAL ? new go.Size(50, 7) : new go.Size(7, 50),
            fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue",
            cursor: HORIZONTAL ? "row-resize" : "col-resize"
          })
      );

    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,
        { routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes, corner: 5 },
        { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true },
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard" }),
        {
          mouseDrop: function (e, link) {  // dropping a copy of some Nodes and Links onto this Link adds them to this Link's Group
            if (!e.shift && !e.control) return;  // cannot change groups with an unmodified drag-and-drop
            var grp = link.containingGroup;
            if (grp !== null) {
              var ok = grp.addMembers(link.diagram.selection, true);
              if (!ok) grp.diagram.currentTool.doCancel();
            }
          },
          layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutAdded
        }
      );

    // define some sample graphs in some of the lanes
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [ // node data
      { key: "Lane1", isGroup: true, color: "lightblue" },
      { key: "Lane2", isGroup: true, color: "lightgreen" },
      { key: "Lane3", isGroup: true, color: "lightyellow" },
      { key: "Lane4", isGroup: true, color: "orange" },
      { key: "oneA", group: "Lane1" },
      { key: "oneB", group: "Lane1" },
      { key: "oneC", group: "Lane1" },
      { key: "oneD", group: "Lane1" },
      { key: "twoA", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoB", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoC", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoD", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoE", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoF", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "twoG", group: "Lane2" },
      { key: "fourA", group: "Lane4" },
      { key: "fourB", group: "Lane4" },
      { key: "fourC", group: "Lane4" },
      { key: "fourD", group: "Lane4" },
    ],
    [ // link data
      { from: "oneA", to: "oneB" },
      { from: "oneA", to: "oneC" },
      { from: "oneB", to: "oneD" },
      { from: "oneC", to: "oneD" },
      { from: "twoA", to: "twoB" },
      { from: "twoA", to: "twoC" },
      { from: "twoA", to: "twoF" },
      { from: "twoB", to: "twoD" },
      { from: "twoC", to: "twoD" },
      { from: "twoD", to: "twoG" },
      { from: "twoE", to: "twoG" },
      { from: "twoF", to: "twoG" },
      { from: "fourA", to: "fourB" },
      { from: "fourB", to: "fourC" },
      { from: "fourC", to: "fourD" }
    ]);

    myDiagram.model.undoManager.isEnabled = true;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sample">
  <div id="myDiagram" style="border: solid 1px blue; width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried setting

```
var HORIZONTAL = true;
```

to

```
var HORIZONTAL = false;
```

I may have the correct orientation though, but the flow is changed. I wonder if the column could just be horizontal and the flow runs like the top-level view.

Comment: @halfer : Sir can you help me with this one. T_T
It's been a day, and I really need to know it ASAP. T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "flow" is changed because setting `HORIZONTAL = false` also changes the Group's layout that it users for its members:

```
myDiagram.groupTemplate =
  $(go.Group, HORIZONTAL ? "Horizontal" : "Vertical",
    {
      ...
      layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout,  // automatically lay out the lane's subgraph
                { direction: HORIZONTAL ? 0 : 90, columnSpacing: 10, layeringOption: go.LayeredDigraphLayout.LayerLongestPathSource }),
```

So you're going to have to modify that `direction: HORIZONTAL ? 0 : 90` to your liking if you don't want it to change when `HORIZONTAL` does.

---

It is not possible to add HTML attributes to each node, but you can store any arbitrary data for each node in the node data itself.

Comment: Can you show me examples of storing arbitrary data to each node sir?

Comment: `someNode.data.ArbitraryValue = 5` will save that value to the model.

Comment: @Simor Sarris : Sir, how about another detailed example? or a link maybe? Like how am i suppose to implement such.

I appreciate your help though, it is quite expedient.

Comment: Sir, may I? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547948/gojs-add-html-attribute-to-nodes